# sessionStorage not working

Tags: html, sessionstorage

My question is the following one... Considering the jQuery code of these two buttons...

```
        $('#submit').bind('click',function(e){          
        var texto = $('#linkSelected').val();
        alert(texto);
        sessionStorage.setItem('nombre', texto);
    });

    $('#load').bind('click',function(e){
        var val = sessionStorage.getItem('nombre');
        alert(val);
    });
```

it seems that when the first jquery click evento is executed, the sessionStorage object doesn't store my 'nombre' item... So... When I press the second button, I don't get raised the alert popup... Who knows the reason ?... I am programming in DreamWeaver CS5.5 and I am testing this in FireFox v11 !...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works like a charm for me in firefox 11. Try this fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/maitrekaio/FLvtJ/

Comment: Thankx for answering me !. It's really weird what's hapenning... I'll try to see this more deeply after work...

Comment: Dude... It worked !; but the thing is that it was me the one who was making things wrong... I was just open the html page not loading it through WampServer... JeJe... Thankx for your time !.